# Element-wise multiplication between vector and scalar with two matrices

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, classification

I have run a classification experiment with 2 classifiers on a dataset with 2 classes and 150 samples. Classifiers are scikit-learn objects with `predict_proba()` method. This method returns an array of shape (`samples`, `classes`) with the probability distribution for each sample. I also computed another matrix `G` with shape (`samples`, 2)  which contains the "importance" of each classifier for each sample.

The final output must be a linear combination of each `predict_proba()` row and the scalar in `G`. Example with one single sample:

```
G = np.array([0.3, 0.7])

classifier_1_proba = np.array([0.6, 0.4])
classifier_2_proba = np.array([0.2, 0.8])

Y = classifier_1_proba * G[0] + classifier_2_proba * G[1]
```

This is easy with just one sample/output, but i don't know how could it be done with multiple samples (e.g. an entire test set).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would work for you:

```py
Y = c1_proba * G[:, 0, None] + c2_proba * G[:, 1, None]
```

Assuming the classifier proba matrices `c1_proba`, `c2_proba` and the weights `G` are all 2D numpy arrays as you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. This indeed get the job done, but i think it will be difficult to scale when using a large number of classifiers, right? I was thinking about a way to keep all `c*_proba` 2D arrays inside a 3D array and manipulate them from there. Do you have any thoughts about this idea?

Comment: How large number of classifiers are we talking here? I guess since the above code uses broadcasting, it is expected to scale well. Did you actually check with many no. of classifiers?

Comment: Or do you mean the no. of classifiers are not fixed or not known beforehand, so writing `Y` as the sum as above is not possible?

Comment: Yes, i can't tell the number of classifiers _a priori_ because it is a parameter for a grid search experiment.

Comment: Yeah I think you can totally do it using a 3D array of classifier predictions `C` and correspondingly reshaped `G` by an operation like `(C * G).sum(axis = ...)`. Specific details for the `axis` parameter will require shapes of `C` and `G`.

Comment: Thanks, your help was very useful. I will accept your answer.